# qmake and osx bundles

Tags: macos, qt, qmake

I want to place some extra information (text files, background pic or others) to an .app-bundle and then access these items from QT. Ok, it is possible to add them using the resource files, but I want to give the user the ability to change the contents relatively easy. The working approach is to do it manually - which is working. However, more beneficial would be if I could do this directly from the qmake .pro files. How do I do this in an elegant way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-bundle-data):

```
RESFILES.files = background.png copyright.txt
RESFILES.path = Contents/Resources
QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA += RESFILES
```